# very slow oracle sql fast after explain plan for

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, explain

Hello i have SQL with few left joins and cases. Time on postgres is around one second and on oracle is 20minuts! (390 row postgres, 300 rows oracle). Configuration of tables are the same in both db. If i run in oracle EXPLAIN PLAN FOR for this sql first, then when i run SQL (without EPF) it is fast as on postgres. I can even make some changes, add colums etc and it still run nice and fast.

Is here someone who understand what is this and what solution i can use in java where query is used?

Comment: Did you push the TURBO button? (Not everyone will understand that). Seriously: you have a problem, but we know nothing about it. We don't have access to your database, we don't know description of your tables, didn't see query you ran, don't know whether you gathered statistics, don't know how explain plan looks like ... Therefore, I'd say that it is rather difficult to assist when that many information is missing. I'm not saying that **I** am capable of helping, but - why wouldn't you help the community help you?

Comment: Only one who can help with this is someone who had this problem (slow sql is fast after running explain plan for) and found or understand why this is happening or might be happening. I want to understand this situation in general. Showing that query is pointless. I am not intrested in answers like: add indexes, use join differently etc.

Comment: Michal, I've been working with Oracle DB for more than 30 years, and did not happen on such a situation. So good luck finding someone who did. You did not give us even the version of Oracle you're using. What may happen is that things like statistics feedback, ... are kicking in after one or 2 executions, and the plan is changing. As @Littefoot said, it's hard to guess from your question.

Comment: Well I'd be more scared from the fact, that with the *same tables* in Oracle returns 90 rows less. This is the first step to see if you compare *comparable*. The question you should ask is why it is possible that Oracle uses a *wrong* execution plan if there is a *better* execution plan used in the second run. (If your intercepntion with `explain plan` plays a role is *very questionalble* - but you should at least say if the two plans differ). The *reasons* for using bad plan if a *good* plan is possible are various, but the top one is *wrong object statistics*, which I'd check first.

Comment: @MichalZajac Perhaps one of the recursive queries that Oracle uses to build the execution plan is running poorly, and when you run the explain plan first the plan is cached and then the actual execution can avoid the parsing overhead. Next time the query runs for 20 minutes, see what other queries are running in the background, paying special attention to SYS queries against the data dictionary. In another session, run a query like this to see activity: `select * from gv$sql where users_executing > 0;`. One guess is that dynamic sampling may need to read a huge amount of data to create estimat

Comment: Hello Jon Heller, thank you for answer. Can i do something in java where i execute this query to do or simulate whatever is happening when i run explain plan in sqlclient first?